# Data type for storing IP addresses

Tags: java, ip

Is there a specific data type for storing IP addresses in Java? I have one specific functionality requirement:

1. Given an IP range and an IP, return true if it falls within it, false otherwise.
   For example: range 10.10.10.1-10.10.11.255 and IP 10.10.10.192 should return true.

I know of `java.net.inetaddress` but I believe it doesn't give me this functionality. Any ideas?

Comment: can you do this with making it String?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An IP (IPv4) is 32 bits (the same size as an int in Java). Since you want to do comparisons using unsigned ints (if you need to support IP's above 128.0.0.0) you need to use longs instead.

```
10.10.10.1 is: (10 << 24) + (10 << 16) + (10 << 8) + 1 = 168430081
10.10.11.255 is: (10 << 24) + (10 << 16) + (11 << 8) + 255 = 168430591

10.10.10.192 is: (10 << 24) + (10 << 16) + (10 << 8) + 192 = 168430272
```

Since `168430081 <= 168430272 && 168430272 <= 168430591`, (In other words 168430272 is between 168430081 and 168430272) your IP is in the range.

Comment: You only need unsigned ints if you want to do a range comparison which crosses the 127.255.255.255 and 128.0.0.0 boundary, in which case you can flip the top bit in your encoding.

Comment: You could always manually detect it, but I think it's easier and don't see anything wrong with using a long other than the 32 wasted bits which is nothing unless he's storing a whole lot of these in an array in memory or something.

Comment: IMHO you should update your example to use `long`, because at the moment your example only uses `int` which is what I suggested. ;)

Comment: How would you convert back to a String in this example?

Comment: @c-qjv0xfi: You can convert it back as: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int a = (ipv4 >> 24) & 127;
        sb.append(a);

        a = (ipv4 >> 16) & 255;
        sb.append("." + a);

        a = (ipv4 >> 8) & 255;
        sb.append("." + a);

        a = ipv4 & 255;
        sb.append("." + a);

        return sb.toString();`

Answer (score 15):

I would use `java.net.InetAddress` or one of its subclasses and write a custom comparator plus a range class:

- Maintaining and debugging are easier with the explicit type InetAddress instead of longs only: Your debugger will actually show "10.10.10.1" and not "168430081"
- IPv6 is either a non-issue or can be implemented without much additional hassle.

One downside of InetAddress is that `getByName` results in a DNS access. You might want to look at [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html)'s `com.google.common.net.InetAddresses` helper class if you want to avoid the penalty for DNS.

```
public enum InetAddressComparator implements Comparator<InetAddress> {

  INSTANCE;

  public int compare(InetAddress first, InetAddress second) {
    byte[] firstBytes = first.getAddress();
    byte[] secondBytes = second.getAddress();
    if (firstBytes.length != secondBytes.length) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot compare IPv4 and IPv6 addresses");
    }
    // getAddress returns bytes in network byte order:
    // the least significant byte is at the last index
    for (int i = firstBytes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      // translate the byte to an int with only the last 8 bits set,
      // effectively treating it as unsigned
      int a = firstBytes[i] & 0xff;
      int b = secondBytes[i] & 0xff;
      if (a < b) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a > b) {
        return 1;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }

}

public class Range<T> {

  private T lower;
  private T upper;
  private Comparator<T> comparator;

  public Range(T lower, T upper, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    if (comparator.compare(lower, upper) <= 0) {
      this.lower = lower;
      this.upper = upper;
    } else {
      this.lower = upper;
      this.upper = lower;
    }
    this.comparator = comparator;
  }

  public boolean contains(T element) {
    return comparator.compare(lower, element) <= 0 &&
      comparator.compare(upper, element) >= 0;
  }

}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InetAddress start = InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.1");
    InetAddress end = InetAddress.getByName("10.10.11.255");
    InetAddress test = InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.192");
    assert InetAddressComparator.INSTANCE.compare(start, test) == -1;
    assert InetAddressComparator.INSTANCE.compare(end, test) == 1;
    assert InetAddressComparator.INSTANCE.compare(test, test) == 0;
    assert new Range<InetAddress>(start, end, InetAddressComparator.INSTANCE)
      .contains(test);
  }
}
```

Comment: both this answer and the one from Ray Tayek looks like fine solutions.  I wonder if there are any new thoughts now that it's been 2 years since the answers.  FWIW it looks like Java 7 does not do a dns check for IP addresses in InetAddress.getByName()

Answer (score 3):

For IPv4 I would use `int` values.  Convert the IP address into a number and you can use number operations.

If you want to do comparisons which range over 127.x.x.x (loop back lan) to 128.x.x.x which is unlikely, but say you do, you can flip the top bit and range comparison will still work.

Using @user1's example. check whether 210.210.210.192 is between 210.210.210.1 and 210.210.211.255

```
210.210.210.1 is: (210 << 24) + (210 << 16) + (210 << 8) + 1 = -757935615
210.210.211.255 is: (210 << 24) + (210 << 16) + (211 << 8) + 255 = -757935105

210.210.210.192 is: (210 << 24) + (210 << 16) + (210 << 8) + 192 = -757935424
```

The last IP address is in range because -757935615 <= -757935424 && -757935424 <= -757935105

Comment: You need long to deal with IPv4 easily because you don't want IPs begining with a byte greate than 127 to be compared using Java's signed comparison.

Comment: Moreover, a long has 64 bits, whereas IPv6 uses 128 bits - so a long won't suffice.

Comment: @user1 IMHO This is only a problem in exceptional cases and it has a simple work around.

Answer (score 3):

If your IP address range can be represented in the common [CIDR format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), you can use [Apache Common's `SubnetUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/index.html).

```
SubnetUtils.SubnetInfo subnet = new SubnetUtils("192.168.0.3/31");
return subnet.isInRange(testIpAddress);
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the IP address into a long integer . 
Refer [Given a list of IP address, how do you find min, max?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808930/given-a-list-of-ip-address-how-do-you-find-min-max) for nice discussion regarding the same issue .

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.*;
class IpRange {
    IpRange(InetAddress from, InetAddress to) {
        if(!from.getClass().equals(to.getClass())) throw new RuntimeException("different versions of ip address!");
        this.from = new BigInteger(from.getAddress());
        this.to = new BigInteger(to.getAddress());
    }
    boolean isInRange(InetAddress inetAddress) {
        BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(inetAddress.getAddress());
        return !(from.compareTo(bigInteger) == 1 || bigInteger.compareTo(to) == 1);
    }
    final BigInteger from, to;
}
public class IpRangeTestCase {
    @Test public void testInRange() throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress from = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 10, 10, 10, 1 });
        InetAddress x = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 10, 10, 10, 42 });
        InetAddress to = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 10, 10, 10, (byte) 192 });
        IpRange ipRange = new IpRange(from, to);
        assertTrue(ipRange.isInRange(from));
        assertTrue(ipRange.isInRange(x));
        assertTrue(ipRange.isInRange(to));
        InetAddress toSmall = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 10, 10, 9, 1 });
        assertFalse(ipRange.isInRange(toSmall));
        InetAddress toBig = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 10, 10, 10, (byte) 193 });
        assertFalse(ipRange.isInRange(toBig));
        InetAddress fromv6=InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x02,(byte)0xb3,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xfe,0x1e,(byte)0x83,0x20});
        InetAddress xv6=InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x02,(byte)0xb3,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xfe,0x1e,(byte)0x83,0x29});
        InetAddress tov6=InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x02,(byte)0xb3,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xfe,0x1e,(byte)0x83,0x40});
        IpRange ipRangev6 = new IpRange(fromv6, tov6);
        assertTrue(ipRangev6.isInRange(xv6));
    }
    @Test (expected=RuntimeException.class) public void testInRangeThrows() throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress v4 = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 10, 10, 10, 1 });
        InetAddress v6=InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x02,(byte)0xb3,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xfe,0x1e,(byte)0x83,0x29});
        new IpRange(v4, v6);
    }
}
```

Comment: I originally considered using BigInteger for the Comparator proposed in my answer, but then decided against that: it happily compares IPv4 and IPv6 addresses with each other, and that may be something that you don't want.

Comment: mine seems to work with ipv6, but does not detect when one is v4 and one is v6.

Comment: i added a test for different version of ip address.

Comment: It does work with internet addresses of arbitrary byte length (i.e. both IPv4 and IPv6), but if you compare v4 with v6, then the v4 address is aliased using ::v4-address. This is actually the same as an "IPv4 compatible" address, which might be extactly what you want, but as there are other v4<->v6 conversion systems as well, it may be the wrong one.

Comment: This is great, though note that you should use the BigInteger constructor which takes the signed-ness into account, i.e. [`BigInteger(1, byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-byte:A-). Otherwise, an address like 255.255.255.255 will be represented as -1.

Answer (score 0):

Just use java's primitive `long`

Comment: IP Address contains 4 numbers, each of them can be stored in 1 byte (0-255). Therefore you need 4 bytes to store the whole IP. After you have a minIp and maxIp values, you can simply test if `testIp > minIp && testIp < maxIp` to see if it is in the range. See @user1 answer for details on how to implements the conversion.

Comment: @Max What about IPv6? `long` will handle the generic case